# Modify the student_grade function using the format method,

Tags: python, string

so that it returns the phrase "X received Y% on the exam". For example, student_grade("Reed", 80) should return "Reed received 80% on the exam".

```
def student_grade(name, grade):
    return ""

print(student_grade("Reed", 80))
print(student_grade("Paige", 92))
print(student_grade("Jesse", 85))
```

I did in this way......

```
def student_grade(name, grade):
    return " {} received {}% on the exam ".format(name, grade)

print(student_grade("Reed", 80))
print(student_grade("Paige", 92))
print(student_grade("Jesse", 85))
```

Here is output:

Reed received 80% on the exam

Paige received 92% on the exam

Jesse received 85% on the exam

Not quite. Check that you're using the format method with
the placeholder curly brackets, with the parameters in the
correct order.

What is wrong in this? why is showing Not quite

Comment: Remember to always tag your question with the language you are using -- [tag:python] in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your answer is correct but course asking you to use the format method with the placeholder curly brackets, with the parameters in the correct order just to know that you captured that tip.

this is the one they are asking from you:

```
def student_grade(name, grade):
        return "{name} received {grade}% on the exam".format (name= name , grade=grade)
    
    print(student_grade("Reed", 80))
    print(student_grade("Paige", 92))
    print(student_grade("Jesse", 85))
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's just a whitespace in your line at the end and start of this value:

```
    " {} received {}% on the exam "
```

It should be like this:

```
    "{} received {}% on the exam"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def student_grade(name, grade):
    return "{name} received {grade}% on the exam".format(name=name,grade=grade)

print(student_grade("Reed", 80))
print(student_grade("Paige", 92))
print(student_grade("Jesse", 85))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like that:

```
return "{0} received {1}% on the exam".format(name,grade)
```

More short and useful !